# Express.js + Sequelize + Form validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, express, sequelize.js

I'm working on my first Express + Sequelize application and would like to use Sequelize's validation mechanism to validate submitted forms without having to re-implement all validations on the frontend (or use additional validation libraries like express-validator, etc.). So, basically I'd like to do something like the following:

```
var signup = function(req, res) {
    res.render('signup', { title: 'Sign-up' });
}

router.get('/signup', signup);

router.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
    User.create({
        email: req.body.email,
        ...
    }).then(function(user) {
        req.flash('info', 'User created successfully.');
        res.redirect('/login');
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // [1] Bring sequelize's error messages into a suitable form somehow
        if (req.xhr) {
            res.json(err);
        }
        else {
            // [2] Fallback for non-JS browsers
            req.flash('error', err);
            signup(req, res);
        }
    });
});
```

1. What's a good way to solve [1] without manually massaging Sequelize error messages into a JSON object?
2. How would you process the JSON on the frontend to have fields marked as containing errors without manually doing so for every field?
3. What's the proposed way to repopulate the form with the posted data? I've searched the web high and low, but it's hard to come across any information about this at all and everybody seems to just manually set the value attribute in the template (which gets tedious when dealing with check-/radio-/combo boxes). I know that this is not a problem when submitting the form via AJAX, but forms should always also work without javascript IMHO.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you separate validation logic from "database" logic. It allow you show validation errors more explicitly and decrease level of complexity.

Move all logic to separate file
`router.post('/signup' create)`

```js
    create(req, res, next){

        createForm.validate(req)
            .then(()=>{
                return createForm.create(req);
            })
            .then((createdUser) => {
                req.flash('info', 'User created successfully.');
                res.redirect('/login');
            })
            .catch((error)=> {

                if(error instanceof ValidationError) {
                    req.flash('error', error);
                    return signup(req, res);
                }
                next(error); //go to handle of unexpected  error
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Node Express Js then I'll recommend you to use Node package [Joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi)

If you don't want to use any library then you can achieve validation by using Sequelize.
First of all, you've to create [Sequelize migrations](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/) and during creating migrations you've to provide primary keys, foreign keys, data types, unique and null constraints.
Migrations can be skipped if your tables have all the above constraints and keys.
The second step is to create [Sequelize Models](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/). During the creation of models make sure your model represents your migration/table structure.
You can add your [Sequelize validations](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/validations-and-constraints/) to your model.

**Example:**
User Migration:

```
module.exports = {
async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('users', {
        id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        email: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            unique: true
        },
        name: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.STRING(50)
        },
        isEnabled: {
            field: 'is_enabled',
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
            defaultValue: true
        },
        createdBy: {
            field: 'created_by',
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        },
        createdAt: {
            field: 'created_at',
            allowNull: false,
            type: 'TIMESTAMP',
            defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('now')
        }
      
    });
},
async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('users');
}
};
```

Model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize)  {
return sequelize.define('users', {
    id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    email: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    name: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        validate: { // Sequelize validation applied
           len: [3, 55]
        }
    },
    
    isEnabled: {
        field: 'is_enabled',
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: true
    },
    createdBy: {
        field: 'created_by',
        allowNull: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: null
    },
    createdAt: {
        field: 'created_at',
        allowNull: false,
        type: 'TIMESTAMP',
        defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('now')
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false
});
```

}

In the above example, I applied validation on the **name** field(min len: 3, max len:50).
Some [sample validation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/validations-and-constraints/) which Sequelize provide

```
is: /^[a-z]+$/i,          // matches this RegExp
  is: ["^[a-z]+$",'i'],     // same as above, but constructing the RegExp from a string
  not: /^[a-z]+$/i,         // does not match this RegExp
  not: ["^[a-z]+$",'i'],    // same as above, but constructing the RegExp from a string
  isEmail: true,            // checks for email format 
  isUrl: true,              // checks for url format 
  isIP: true,               // checks for IPv4 (129.89.23.1) or IPv6 format
  isIPv4: true,             // checks for IPv4 (129.89.23.1)
  isIPv6: true,             // checks for IPv6 format
  isAlpha: true,            // will only allow letters
  isAlphanumeric: true,     // will only allow alphanumeric characters, so "_abc" will fail
  isNumeric: true,          // will only allow numbers
  isInt: true,              // checks for valid integers
  isFloat: true,            // checks for valid floating point numbers
  isDecimal: true,          // checks for any numbers
  isLowercase: true,        // checks for lowercase
  isUppercase: true,        // checks for uppercase
  notNull: true,            // won't allow null
  isNull: true,             // only allows null
  notEmpty: true,           // don't allow empty strings
  equals: 'specific value', // only allow a specific value
  contains: 'foo',          // force specific substrings
  notIn: [['foo', 'bar']],  // check the value is not one of these
  isIn: [['foo', 'bar']],   // check the value is one of these
  notContains: 'bar',       // don't allow specific substrings
  len: [2,10],              // only allow values with length between 2 and 10
  isUUID: 4,                // only allow uuids
  isDate: true,             // only allow date strings
  isAfter: "2011-11-05",    // only allow date strings after a specific date
  isBefore: "2011-11-05",   // only allow date strings before a specific date
  max: 23,                  // only allow values <= 23
  min: 23,                  // only allow values >= 23
  isCreditCard: true,       // check for valid credit card numbers
```